# Photoshop Javascript script - is there a way to not have to manually click ok when using saveAs?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a photoshop script thats working and does  everything I need, except when I call the following in the last line of my script:

```
    var saveLocation = File("/Users/user/Desktop/cats/catT1"+i+".jpg");
    var config = new JPEGSaveOptions();
    config.quality = 10;

    app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveLocation, config);
```

It opens the saveAs window for me to click Save, then once I have it opens a JPEG options window in which I need to click OK.

I want to run this script over many items and so really need a way to automate / eliminate the clicking...

If I add displayDialogs = DialogModes.OFF; to my script, I see the following when running:
[image: error]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Difficult to know without seeing more of your code. However, I guess you haven't assigned a `new File('/some/path/file.jpg')` to the `saveLocation` variable or haven't assigned a new `JPEGSaveOptions` constructor to the `config` variable. Consider [this example](https://paste.ee/p/hfC7b) that, on macOS, will save a JPEG named `foobar.jpg` to the desktop folder.

Comment: Thanks @RobC - have added the other code

Comment: Even if I adapt to copy your example by adding the 'new' key word before File in saveLocation, I still get the saveAs popUp and have to click save...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
yourPath = File('~/desktop/jpgFile');
(jpg = new JPEGSaveOptions).quality = 12
activeDocument.saveAs(yourPath, jpg, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply suppress any dialog boxes with this at the start of a script:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF
```

For debugging you can put them to ERROR `displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR;` or normal `displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL;`

Bearing in mind that this will change the state of Photoshop, so I've taken to adding them to all myscripts, switching them off to start with and switching them back on at the end.

Comment: Interesting - so will that act as if you've responded positively to each? "Save" and "OK" in this case? It's throwing an error now - added to question

Comment: @PeteG That's my fault! It was a typo. It should be `NO` not `OFF`.  `displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF ` I've corrected my answer to reflect this